# Matrix in Safecracker form displaying a row even though min row setting is set to zero

Tags: matrix

I have a Safecracker form with several matrix fields. All are currently configured with minimum rows set at zero, however a couple of fields used to have their minimum row setting set to one. Now those fields show one row even though the setting has been changed to zero. The other rows properly show the "No rows exist yet" message with the link to add a row.

How can I 'reset' the offending fields such that they display no rows?

Comment: I've just checked and these fields show an existing row even in the control panel. So Safecracker isn't an issue in and of itself.

Comment: If you delete those 'blank' rows do they stay deleted after saving the entry?

Comment: I'm unable to delete the blank rows as the delete option is grayed out.

Comment: So if this is only happening to entries that were created before you made the setting change, and new entries work correctly, have you tried deleting the empty rows directly in the database?

Comment: No. That's not it. All new entries display the row for any field that was once set to "1" and then switched to "0". It's as if the field is 'hung up' and can't recognize the new min rows setting.